# Let $a,b\in G$ (a group) such that $ab=ba$, $|a| = m$ and $|b| = n$. If $(m, n) = 1$, then $|ab|= mn$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $a,b\in G$ (a group) such that $ab=ba$, $|a| = m$ and $|b| = n$. If $(m, n) = 1$, then $|ab|= mn$.

Here I understand that $G$ is abelian and that this computes to $a^{mn} = b^{mn} = 1,$ and $m,n$ are relatively prime. But I really don't know about a step-by-step process of proving this.

Comment: I think you mean $|ab|=mn.$

Comment: And no, it is not true that $m=n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I thought so too... but this is what the question says.. and it is confusing me.

Comment: Probably a mistake, because as stated, the problem doesn’t make any sense. Specifically, $ab=|mn|$ is meaningless.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh thank you for that! Just realised that (m,n)=1 was referring to the gcd, and that m,n are relatively prime.